# Java Multidimensional Array Outprint

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing, out

I dont understand, why these numbers are printed out. Shouldn't it just out print 3 2 1? Instead, it prints:
3 
0 
0 
0 
2 
0 
0 
0 
1

Thank you for your help :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, j, n = 3;

    int[][] polje = new int[n][n];

    polje[0][0] = 3;
    polje[1][1] = 2;
    polje[2][2] = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(polje[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have created a 2D array, basically a square of numbers with three rows and three columns. You have assigned numbers to three positions in this square; the other 6 positions are zero.

Answer (score 0):

you have set likewise,

```
3 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 1
```

so obviously you get, 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1

if you want to print only 3 2 1 then made this changes only,

```
if(i == j){
   System.out.print(polje[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```